# reorder/sort ng-repeat list dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I working on angularjs. I am trying to reorder the ng-repeat list.
There is list of online users.[image]
Users can receive messages anytime. Whenever user receive the message i update the ui and show the recent message under the name.
I am trying to sort the user list based on the users who receive the recent message. The user who receive the messages should come at the top.

Some codes- 
Userlist controller:

```
$scope.$watch('service.get.userList()', function (values) {

    var result = [];
    angular.forEach(values, function (value) {


        processChatService.registerObserverCallback('lastMessage', function () { //i call this event when user receives the message
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                value.l = processChatService.get.lastMessage(value.u); //returns the recent message
                value.time = processChatService.get.lastMessageTime(value.u); //returns time
            });
        });
        value.l = processChatService.get.lastMessage(value.u); //it returns null if user havent recieve message
        value.time = processChatService.get.lastMessageTime(value.u);

        result.push(value);
    });
    $scope.users = result;
});
```

**html**:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search"> <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="click(user)" ng-href="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="thumb-userlist-sm pull-left mr">
                                    <img class="img-circle"  ng-src="{{ user.p }}" alt="...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <div class="message-sender">{{ user.n }}</div>
                                <div class="message-preview">{{user.l}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="pull-right">{{user.time}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="line-separator"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to check out build-in filter called `orderBy` ;) then ng-repeat becomes `ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search | orderBy:'time'"`

Comment: take care when using `orderBy` on large lists. filters are executed twice per digest cycle upon a change, and this may incur an unacceptable performance overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you'll probably want to do is order the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search | orderBy: 'time'">
```

This will order the `users` on the `time` property of each `user`. It's also possible to reverse the sort order with `-time`.

For more information on the orderBy filter, check the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy).

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using orderBy.Now it depends upon the requirement.In your case it is time.

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users  | filter:search | orderby:'time'"> <a class="list-group-item" ng-click="click(user)" ng-href="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="thumb-userlist-sm pull-left mr">
                                    <img class="img-circle"  ng-src="{{ user.p }}" alt="...">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-8">
                                <div class="message-sender">{{ user.n }}</div>
                                <div class="message-preview">{{user.l}}</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-2">
                                <div class="pull-right">{{user.time}}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <div class="line-separator"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```